# Visual Studio 2015 Cannot find list of available events short cuts

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Just started using VS2015 and everything seems pretty nice except one thing which I cannot figure out how to enable or show on the code editor. Plz See pic below. Do you call this form event drop list?
[image]

How can I bring this back?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that one of C# solutions I got from Enterprise library hand-on-lab file showed the navigation bar (Yes, it's called Navigation Bar). And finally found that option.
Go to Tools>Option>Text Editor>select your language or all language>Navigation bar

[image]

Yes!!!