# Not seeing the input fields and dropdowns i have created

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a pretty simple .aspx page with some fields added like such:

```
<form id="form2" runat="server">
                        <label for="name">First Name*</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="first_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="first_name"
                            ErrorMessage="First name is required." ToolTip="First name is required." ValidationGroup="requestquote">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        <label for="name">Last Name*</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="last_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="last_name"
                            ErrorMessage="Last name is required." ToolTip="Last name is required." ValidationGroup="requestquote">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

But when i go to the `.vb` file i don't see all my fields listed. How can i fix this?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791371/visual-studio-2015-cannot-find-list-of-available-events-short-cuts

Comment: This seem not relevant as the bar does show for me as shown in the screenshot. Its just that the text fields that i created are not listed.

Comment: Remove them and add them again. Sometimes they are not registered (usually when copied from somewhere else)

Comment: Maybe you need to check the `<% Page inherit ="your_web_form" %>` make sure it's the same as your `class` name

Comment: Controls did not get generated into your *.designer.vb file. Check for syntax errors in the rest of that aspx page. That could prevent variables from generating. Then try to display designer mode, back to markup mode and save changes. Last try is to write them to yourpage.aspx.designer.vb file manually if everything else fails.

Comment: the inherit tag was incorrect as pointed out by moiyd